# How to use environment in React?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to set up the environment profiles using .env properties files.

Basically, I have .env and .env.local.
The content is the following:

> .env
>
> `USE_AXIOS_MOCKS=false`
>
> .env.local
>
> `USE_AXIOS_MOCKS=true`

When I tried to log the value, I always got `undefined` and I've realized (after a few hours and because I read the related documentation) that we need to use REACT_APP_ prefix (ex. `REACT_APP_USE_AXIOS_MOCKS=true`)

Do you know what is the reason for such a silly "limitation" (in my opinion) without any log to inform you that your value is ignored?

Comment: From the docs: `The environment variables are embedded during the build time.` I'd argue, that it is basically a pattern the guys over at create-react-app decided to use (which I assume you are using).

Comment: using [dotenv packange](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm already using react-script that are using dotenv. I solved the issue but I'm still surprised that it is working with the prefix REACT_APP_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for feedback on React design decisions. This question should probably be filed as an issue or feedback on the React github repo instead.

Comment: It can help other people with the same issues as well. Do you agree?